# C++ Conceptual problem with (Pointer) Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a structure usually containing a pointer to an `int`. However, in some special cases, it is necessary that this int pointer points to another pointer which then points to an int. Wow: I mentioned the word pointer 5 times so far!

- Is this even possible?

I thought about it that way: Instead of using a second int pointer, which is most likely not possible as my main int pointer can only point to an int and not to another int pointer, I could make it a reference like this:

```
int intA = 1;
int intB = 2;
int& intC = intB;

int* myPointers[ 123 ];
myPointers[ 0 ] = &intA;
myPointers[ 1 ] = &intB;
myPointers[ 3 ] = &intC;
```

So the above would do what I want: The reference to `intB` (`intC`) behaves quite like I want it to (If it gets changed it also changes `intB`)

- The problem: I can't change references once they are set, right? Or is there a way?

Everything in short: How do I get a value to work with `*` (pointers) and `**` (pointers to pointers)?

Comment: You might get better suggestions if you take a step back to *what* you are trying to achieve instead of *how*.

Comment: Yep, what @gf said. What you want *could* be done with a couple of casts, but the answer really depends on the context, on what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

`int*` and `int**` are different types so you can't use one as the other without using a potentially non-portable cast.

In the declaration:

```
int& intC = intB;
```

The reference `intC` will always refer to the `int` `intB`. The binding cannot be changed.

You could use a union to support a type that could be either an `int*` or an `int**` but you would need to be certain when you're reading, which member of the union is valid at any point.

```
union PIntOrPPInt
{
    int* pint;
    int** ppint;
};

int intA;
int intB;
int* pintC = &intB;

PIntOrPPInt myPointers[ 123 ];

myPointers[ 0 ].pint = &intA;
myPointers[ 1 ].pint = &intB;
myPointers[ 3 ].ppint = &pintC;
```

Comment: What sort of approach do you mean? If you want to store something that could be one of two types then you need a type than can support this. A `union` is probably the simplest such type.

Comment: @Ptr: I suppose you could have an array of `void*` and use a `reinterpret_cast` to convert to the correct type as needed. I don't see this having any advantages over the `union` solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a pointer to `intB` in both array elements:

```
myPointers[ 1 ] = &intB;
myPointers[ 3 ] = &intB;
```

This way both elements point to the same variable and `*myPointers[1]` will always be the same as `*myPointers[3]`. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Not really: I need a variable which is "compatible" to the type int* but points to an element of myPointers. Basically: A value stored in myPointers, which can *change* its target, and does itself point to a variable in myPointers again.

Answer (score 0):

We rarely if ever use pointers to pointers in C++. Instead, like you suggest, we use reference to pointers. That said, C++ is a strongly-typed, static-typed language. So you have to decide at compile-time what your array elements are going to point to.

One approach is to wrap the array elements in a class:

```
struct P {
    P() : p(0) { }
    P(int* p) : p(p) { }
    P(int** p) : p(*p) { }
    operator int*() const { return p; }
    int *p;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int *i1 = new int(5);
    int **i2 = &i1;
    int *&i3 = i1;
    P arr[4] = {i1, i2, i3, P()};
    delete i1;
    return 0;
}
```